# Match field with id and insert data - meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a collection with the following data.

```
{
    containerId: "content-left",
    content: "<p>Some text for the left side</p>"
},
{
    containerId: "content-right",
    content: "<p>Some text for the right side</p>"
}
```

I want to loop through every document and take the containerId then match it up with an id and insert only the content from the containerId that matched the  id.

// TEMPLATE

```
<template name="mainLeft">

    <section id="content-left" class="content">
        {{#each copy}}
            {{{content}}}
        {{/each}}
    </section>

</template>

<template name="mainRight">

    <section id="content-right" class="content">
        {{#each copy}}
            {{{content}}}
        {{/each}}
    </section>

</template>
```

At the moment I'm just getting all the data from the collection and inserting it in every section so it looks like this

```
<section id="content-left" class="content">
    <p>Some text for the left side</p>
    <p>Some text for the right side</p>
</section>

<section id="content-right" class="content">
    <p>Some text for the left side</p>
    <p>Some text for the right side</p>
</section>
```

// HELPER

```
  UI.registerHelper('copy', function() {
    return ContentCollection.find();
  });
```

So it should end up looking like this

```
<section id="content-left" class="content">
    <p>Some text for the left side</p>
</section>

<section id="content-right" class="content">
    <p>Some text for the right side</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register two seperate template helpers instead.

```
UI.registerHelper('copyLeft', function() {
    return ContentCollection.find({containerId:'content-left'});
});

UI.registerHelper('copyRight', function() {
    return ContentCollection.find({containerId:'content-right'});
});
```

Then you can replace the copy in the template with copyLeft and copyRight

```
<section id="content-left" class="content">
    {{#each copyLeft}}
        {{{content}}}
    {{/each}}
</section>

<section id="content-right" class="content">
    {{#each copyRight}}
        {{{content}}}
    {{/each}}
</section>
```

If you want more flexibility you can also pass arguments to the helper

```
UI.registerHelper('copy', function(container) {
    return ContentCollection.find({containerId:container});
});
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<section id="content-left" class="content">
    {{#each copy 'content-left'}}
        {{{content}}}
    {{/each}}
</section>

<section id="content-right" class="content">
    {{#each copy 'content-right'}}
        {{{content}}}
    {{/each}}
</section>
```

Comment: Hi Bouke, thanks but I'm looking for a way that I can just add sections and create the data and the rest will happen by itself? I would like for there to be much more sections in the future so that would mean that I would end up with a bunch of helpers, each for every section.